# Tamanho de array bidimensional não está sendo definido

Tags: java, array

Criei uma matriz e coloquei para ela inicializar com os valores passados no construtor, porem ela não está inicializando. Criei o objeto, joguei os valores, porem quando chamo o método para mostrar a matriz, ela não aparece, como se não tivesse sido criada. Alguem pode me ajudar?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ExerMatriz {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    private int linha;
    private int coluna;

    ExerMatriz(){
        System.out.println("Digite a quantidade de linhas");
        this.setLinha(s.nextInt()); 
        System.out.println("Digite a quantidade de colunas");
        this.setColuna(s.nextInt()); 

    }


    private int m[][] = new int[this.getLinha()][this.getColuna()];

    public void mostrarMatriz(){
        for(int i=0; i< m.length;i++){
            for(int j=0; j<m[0].length;j++){
                System.out.print(this.m[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }


    public int[][] getM() {
        return m;
    }

    public void setM(int[][] m) {
        this.m = m;
    }
    public int getLinha() {
        return linha;
    }

    public void setLinha(int linha) {
        this.linha = linha;
    }

    public int getColuna() {
        return coluna;
    }

    public void setColuna(int coluna) {
        this.coluna = coluna;
    }
}
```

Comment: Diego, muito obrigado mesmo. Eu pensei antes no que você disse, que ela era criada, porem não sabia como fazer. Se puder tirar só mais uma dúvida... O segundo for, (int j=0; j<m[0].length;j++), pega a coluna. Entretanto, [0].length, só pega se for da mesma dimensão da linha, correto? Como faço se for de tamanhos diferentes?

Comment: Relendo sua dúvida, percebo que não havia entendido corretamente, você pode faze uma nova pergunta para esclarecer isso :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que você está iniciando e definindo o tamanho das dimensões do vetor ao instanciar sua classe. Quando os métodos `this.getLinha()` e `this.getColuna()` são invocados na linha:

```
private int m[][] = new int[this.getLinha()][this.getColuna()];
```

eles retornam 0, pois `linha` e `coluna` são variáveis do tipo `int`, e tipos primitivos numéricos como `int` são iniciados pelo java com valor 0. Logo sua matriz tem dimensões 0x0.

Essa linha é executada quando a classe `ExerMatriz` é instanciada, ou seja, quando você faz `ExerMatriz e =  new ExerMatriz()`, e não adianta definir o tamanho depois, o atributo já está criado e iniciado.

Sugiro que você crie um construtor por onde você inicie o vetor já com os tamanhos coletados do `Scanner`. Outro ponto, dentro da própria classe, não há muita necessidade dela usar os próprios `get` e `set`, uma vez que ela pode acessar seus próprios atributos diretamente:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ExerMatriz {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    private int linha;
    private int coluna;

    public ExerMatriz(){
        System.out.println("Digite a quantidade de linhas");
        this.linha(s.nextInt()); 
        System.out.println("Digite a quantidade de colunas");
        this.coluna(s.nextInt()); 
        this.m = new int[linha][coluna];
    }



    private int m[][];

    public void mostrarMatriz(){
        for(int i=0; i< m.length;i++){
            for(int j=0; j<m[0].length;j++){
                System.out.print(this.m[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }


    public int[][] getM() {
        return m;
    }

    public void setM(int[][] m) {
        this.m = m;
    }
    public int getLinha() {
        return linha;
    }

    public void setLinha(int linha) {
        this.linha = linha;
    }

    public int getColuna() {
        return coluna;
    }

    public void setColuna(int coluna) {
        this.coluna = coluna;
    }
}
```

Vale ressaltar também que esta matriz está sendo criada vazia, pois em momento algum do código ela é preenchida com valores.